# How do i make a script in tampermonkey to auto click

Tags: javascript, click, tampermonkey, auto

I tried auto clicking using this function.

```
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("*********").click();}, 1500);
```

By putting the number "15648632145687", but failed

Can any one help , the number changes on each and every page so I would need a script which can identify this value even after it's changed and click

This is the X Path (`/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a`)

This is the image for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` only works with an `id` attribute, which you example HTML lacks. Instead you could select the element via its `data` attribute.

It's worth noting that strictly speaking you shouldn't use `data` attributes to select HTML elements in JavaScript due to poorer performance than alternative approaches, and the fact that the `data` attribute wasn't intended to be used that way.

Nonetheless, for your use case, it'll likely make for a good solution:

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  // Select the element by its data attribute
  var element = document.querySelector('[data-search-value]');
  element.click();

  // Example of getting the value of the data attribute
  var elementValue = element.getAttribute('data-search-value');
  console.log('elementValue', elementValue);
}, 1500);
```

```html
<a href="#" data-search-value="15648632145687">15648632145687</a>
```